# Declaration file for function-module (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I use a node module that's not found by typings and doesn't exist in definelytyped.

the basic use of the module is:

```
import * as someFunc from 'some-module';

someFunc("some string");
```

As you can see, this module exports a function as its default. I haven't figured out how to write the declaration file for it.

This is the best I managed to do:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
    export default function someFunc(someArg: string): void;
}
```

BTW it does work JavaScriptly. It's only the TypeScript bothers me.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declaration:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
  var exportFunction : (arg: string) => void;
  export = exportFunction;
}
```

usage:

```
import * as someFunc from "some-module";
someFunc(a)';
```

Is how this can be done.

Comment: The opening parenthesis (in var exportFunction = (arg: string) => void;) is marked with red, saying: TS7011: Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

Comment: fixed. Should be declaration of type instead of an assignement, change = to :